# Refresh fragment layout from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a view pager which contains three fragments and each fragments has a **recyclerView**.

**Fragment2** has **recycler2**. when we click on **recycler2** item it is removed from **fragment2** and added to **fragment1** recyclerItem.

if there is an item in **recycler1** the list is refreshed when I call the **notifyDatasetChanged()** of **recyler1** adapter.

But when there no item in the list the data is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing like below issue shouldn't be there, please confirm.

1) Fragment2 --> recycler2-->ItemClicked-->removed item from existing data set--->notifyDatasetChanged.

On the other side

Fragment1 --> recycler1-->added new item into existing data set--->notifyDatasetChanged.

Comment: Can help you surely if you provide the adapter's code for both recycler1 and recycler2.